# Replacement for deprecated Release function

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

As of C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo (and perhaps earlier), the [`FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Release()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Release) method is deprecated.

I use this method on some `TForm` objects for delayed destruction. All I can find (see [these docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TObject.Free)) is that (in C++) `delete` should be used instead, but I don't believe this marks a form for delayed destruction.

Is there a replacement for `Release()` that one ought to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why Embarcadero has deprecated `Release()` or what they intend it to be replaced with, but you could try using [`TThread::ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) to `delete` the `TForm` object, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::ReleaseMe()
{
    // Release()
    TThread::ForceQueue(NULL, &DeleteMe);
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::DeleteMe()
{
    delete this;
}
```

Or, if you are using a Clang-based compiler, you can use a C++11 lambda instead:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::ReleaseMe()
{
    // Release()
    TThread::ForceQueue(nullptr, [this](){ delete this; });
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this solution because it seems Embarcadero doesn't have a standard replacement as of yet, and so a strategy like this is the right strategy unless or until they bring in a replacement. For the time being, I'm going to simply leave the Release calls, and if they are no longer supported in a future release and there's no replacement function, I'll probably implement this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi you can use

```
ReleaseForm;
```

I would assume it is there for C++ Builder too.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 10.4 there is an action in the `OnClose` event of `TForm`. I assume they want you to set it to `caFree` instead of calling `Release`.